# Unable to track if onProviderDisabled and Enabled in android gps tracker

Tags: android

```
public class Gpstracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabled"+arg0, 10000).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabled"+arg0, 10000).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my GpsTracker class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gpstracker gps=new Gpstracker();
    }
}
```

This is MainActivity : When I enable wifi or Gps then it not display toast same if we disable its not display toast message that your wifi is Off please help how to check that Location is Enabled or disabled.
Please tell me how to detect using service that LocationLisner is on Or Off is enable to display

Comment: Where are you registering and unregistering listener?

Comment: how i will registering and unregistering listener can u please tell me Solution i am doing it first time

Comment: @MysticMagic can u please tell me Solution i just want enable and disable show toast if we enable Gps and disable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `LocationListener` to work, you need to `request` location updates in following manner:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, gps);  //time and distance as per your requirement. gps is your listener class object
```

You can unregister listener using `removeLocationUpdates` when app is going to be destroyed or in background. Depends on requirement.

```
lm.removeUpdates(gps);
```

**BUT**

you are saying that you just want notification of GPS enabled or disabled. So I would suggest you go with BroadcastReceiver approach.

In manifest, register receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.pkg.MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Your MyReceiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver   extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            //Show toast of enabled
        }
         else
         {
            //Show toast of disabled
         }
    }
}
```

If you want updates only when your application is in foreground, then register in `onResume` of your activity, and unregister in `onPause`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok wait let me try i will give me detail

Comment: http://pastie.org/9769256 this exception is coming : here is my class http://pastie.org/9769255 manifiest http://pastie.org/9769254

Comment: WHY ARE YOU MIXING both approaches? Any way, you have null pointer on Gpstracker.java:22. What's that line?

Comment: Null on MyReceiver.java:16. You should try & solve NPE by looking at logcat and code.

Comment: final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  this Line Exception coming

Comment: http://pastie.org/9769267 i tried this  but not getting toast messge when i off or on gps or Aceesmyloition

Comment: @Edge your onReceive has argument is `Context arg0` and you use `context`. Change to `Context context` in `onReceive`.

Comment: hello i just want display toast message when we switch off and on Gpstracer

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context error is coming

Comment: one more thing i want to ask that i dont want set it on Gpsi just want to set on acess my location coz location we can get Using 3g and wifi also